# Customize text for invalid fields in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I am trying to display a customized message when the text entered does not match the pattern.
Following is the code I have used.

```
<input pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]" name="firstName" id="firstname" required="" type="text" />
```

When I enter a valid text like 'akshay'; it is showing me the invalid message:

> 'Please match the requested format'

Also, I want to change this message to a customized one. I tried using the code given above but its is not working. Below is the code I have used below:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("firstname").addEventListener("invalid", function (e) {
var elem = e.target;

if (elem.value != "") {
    e.target.setCustomValidity('Cannot contain special characters');
}
});
</script>
```

Please help me with this code.

Comment: see this http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use oninvalid method in the input tag

```
<input pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]*" name="firstName" id="firstname" required="required"
type="text" oninvalid="oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity(this.willValidate?'':'Cannot contain special characters')" />
```

Comment: Thanks Tamil Selvan.. It works as I Wanted.. But it is becoming invalid when I give a valid text like 'akshay'..